# Jquery on click input does not work if input is disabled

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to tell jQuery to only target elements that as disabled?

https://jsfiddle.net/o80cqp4h/

```
$(document).on("click", "input", function () {
   console.log('click');
   $(this).prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Comment: Disabling an item removes the ability to click it.  Think about a button, the purpose of disabling a button is so it cannot be clicked.

Comment: The problem is with disabled="disabled", you can never trigger click event.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery ignores clicks on disabled elements (sort of), so the trick is to detect the click higher up the chain, and then find out if it was on an input element:

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    $clicked = $(e.toElement);
    if ($clicked.is("input:disabled")) {
        $clicked.prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

If you have to support firefox, you have to get even hackier.

https://jsfiddle.net/o80cqp4h/3/ <-- with firefox support

https://jsfiddle.net/o80cqp4h/1/

Comment: Ahh firefox, just added a really hacky solution to support that

Comment: well, not really. I can't change the value of the input after it "became active"

Comment: Thanks for not being one of the others to just say you can  never do this.  I know I had seen it done before.

Comment: I may keep playing with it, because https://jsfiddle.net/o80cqp4h/4/ does not work.  (When the input is later added dynamically) I could always run the build function after adding it.